# Why are the results of ee.Reducer.fixedHistogram() fractional (Earth Engine)

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am calculating a histogram for an area of interest using `ee.Reducer.fixedHistogram()`. The pixel count per bin is often a fraction, but not always. I was expecting integer results - the count of whole pixels per bin. Why are the results fractions of a pixel?

Here is my code - inspect the histogram table and hover over bars in the histogram chart to see the results:

```js
// Define an image.
var img = ee.Image('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR/LC08_038029_20180810')
  .select('B6');

// Define an area of interest.
var aoi = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
  [[[-110.5241853160436, 44.82231727808245],
    [-110.5241853160436, 44.474355785401221],
    [-110.06001295276235, 44.47355785401221],
    [-110.06001295276235, 44.82231727808245]]], null, false);

// Show image and AOI on the map.
Map.centerObject(img, 8);  
Map.addLayer(img, {min: 100, max: 3500});
Map.addLayer(aoi);

// Calculate a histogram for the pixels in the API.
var swir1HistDict = img.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.fixedHistogram(0, 5000, 250),
  geometry: aoi,
  scale: 30,
  maxPixels: 1e13
});

// A dictionary was returned, get the ee.Array results.
var swir1HistArray = ee.Array(swir1HistDict.get('B6'));

// Convert the array to a list so that it can be mapped over.
var swir1HistList = swir1HistArray.toList();
print(swir1HistList);

// Convert the array into a feature list.
var swir1HistFtList = swir1HistList.map(function(li) {
  li = ee.List(li);
  return ee.Feature(aoi, {'Value': li.get(0), 'Frequency': li.get(1)});
});

// Convert the feature list into a feature collection.
var swir1HistFtCol = ee.FeatureCollection(swir1HistFtList);

// Chart the histogram.
var chart = ui.Chart.feature.byFeature({
  features: swir1HistFtCol,
  xProperty: 'Value',
  yProperties: 'Frequency'})
  .setChartType('ColumnChart');
print(chart);
```

[Code Editor script](https://code.earthengine.google.com/acb4f51ad1d05da0595146de7f6f5559?as_external)

Comment: If you only want complete pixels to take into the histogram (usually preferred in histograms), use the `unweigthed()` reducer. [see link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/58191c6ed69908cc9d113ec90175d00f?as_external). Also read [here](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/reducers_reduce_region) and [here](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/reducers_weighting) to learn how that works (`fixedHistogram()` is a weigthed reducer, as Justin points out).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ee.Reducer.fixedHistogram()` reducer considers pixel fraction for intersection with the `geometry` parameter argument of `.reduceRegion()`, not simply binary yes/no pixel intersects the geometry. If the geometry bisects a pixel, that pixel only gets counted as 0.5 of a pixel when calculating frequency, for instance.

The following is an example to illustrate this. A geometry is drawn to intersect 9 pixels. The corners of the rectangle geometry are tied to the center of the corner pixels (approximately). Given this arrangement, there should be 4 pixels that contribute 0.25 to the frequency table, 4 pixels that contribute 0.5, and 1 that contributes 1.0. Run the script and inspect the histogram table to see that this is true.

*Note*: you can change this behavior by calling `.unweighted()` on the `ee.Reducer.fixedHistogram()` reducer (other reducers as well - [info](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/reducers_weighting)).

```js
// Define an area of interest to count pixels with fixedHistogram.
var aoi = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
  [[[-122.02261048887823, 37.15910696904978],
    [-122.02261048887823, 37.14077254650685],
    [-122.00458604429815, 37.14077254650685],
    [-122.00458604429815, 37.15910696904978]]], null, false);

// Define a random image to get some values.
var img = ee.Image.random(0)
  .multiply(100)
  .round()
  .toInt()
  .reproject({crs: 'EPSG:4326', scale: 1000});

// Display the image and the AOI to the map.
Map.centerObject(aoi, 14);
Map.addLayer(img, {min: 0, max: 100}, 'Random');
Map.addLayer(aoi, {color: 'red'}, 'AOI');

// Calculate a histogram for the pixels in the AOI.
var swir1HistDict = img.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.fixedHistogram(0, 101, 101),
  geometry: aoi,
  scale: 1000,
  maxPixels: 1e13
});

// A dictionary was returned, get the ee.Array results.
var swir1HistArray = ee.Array(swir1HistDict.get('random'));
print(swir1HistArray);
```

[Code Editor script](https://code.earthengine.google.com/9b6247bd8011ca1ea911b852177a7198?as_external)

[image]